# Why a pointer to pointer to a struct works in the following code but not a single pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
  int data;
  struct node* next;
}node;

void push(node* head,int d);

int main()
{
  node* head = NULL;
  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  while(n!=-1){
    push(head,n);
    scanf("%d",&n);
  }

  node* temp = head;
  while(temp!=NULL){
    printf("%d ->",temp->data);
    temp=temp->next;
  }
  printf("NULL");
}

void push(node* head,int d)
{
  node* new = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  new->data=d;
  if(head==NULL){
    new->next=NULL;
    head=new;
  }else {
    new->next=head;
    head=new;
  }

}
```

The above code does't work. It should be displaying the elements entered till a -1 is entered, but it doesn't do that.

`push(head,n);`

```
void push(node** head,int d)
{
  node* new = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  new->data=d;
  if(*head==NULL){
    new->next=NULL;
    *head=new;
  }else {
    new->next=*head;
    *head=new;
  }

}
```

After adding these two changes, the code works fine.
Why does replacing single pointer with double pointer makes the code work, while everything else is kept same?

Comment: "The above code does't work..." - it does work. Confirmed with online compiler. " It should be displaying the elements entered..." - **it is** displaying elements until `-1` is typed with a keyboard.

Comment: I tried it on [Online C Compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) but it does't work, it just shows the text "NULL" which should be printed after all the characters are printed.

Comment: Your link points me to an empty C program. The link does not correspond to your code. Your program reads and prints all numbers and after that the program prints `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Well. When you want to modify a integer variable inside a function, you pass it by reference. That is, you pass its address.

`int x = 5;`

```
void change_value (int* x)
{
    (*x) = 7; // is not 5 anymore
}
```

With pointers is the same. If you want to modify a pointer. You have to pass it by reference. That is, you have to pass its address. Which is a pointer to a pointer.

```
int* ptr_x = &x;

void change_pointer (int** ptr_x)
{
    *ptr_x = NULL; // is not &x anymore
}
```

In your first code:

`head = new;`

this does nothing outside the function, it only sets the local variable head to new inside the function. Whatever variable the caller passed in will remain unchanged.you need to use pointers or  references.

Answer (score 0):

First you should take a look at how pointer work in general, you will need the knowledge.

For your question,

```c
node* head = NULL; //a pointer, so basically an int
push(head,n); //just passes this int as a copy, so any changes will just affect copy and wont be passed back.
```